# The value of undefined after calling the function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I write quiz apps and I have a problem. Namely, he wants me to have four variants of the answer. e.g. Java, C, Python, JS. I currently have Java, C, Python, undefined. What could be the problem? Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aplikacja quizu</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="aplikacja, quiz, pytania, odpowiedzi">
    <meta name="description" content="Podstawowa aplikacja do quizu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-quiz">
            <div class="content-quiz-questions">
                <h2 id="header-questions">Question</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content-quiz-answers">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_a" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="a" for="answer_a">Question</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_b" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="b" for="answer_b">Question</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_c" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="c" for="answer_c">Question</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_d" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="d" for="answer_d">Question</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-quiz">
            <button type="submit">Wyślij</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const headQuestions = document.getElementById('header-questions');
headQuestions.innerHTML = questQuiz();

const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('button');
function questQuiz() {
    const questArr = [
        'What is the most used programming language in 2019?',
        'Who is the President of US?',
        'What does HTML stand for?',
        'What year was JavaScript launched?'
    ];
    let emptyStr = '';
    for (let i = questArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        emptyStr = questArr[i];
    }
    return emptyStr;
}

const answerA = document.getElementById('a');
answerA.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerB = document.getElementById('b');
answerB.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerC = document.getElementById('c');
answerC.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerD = document.getElementById('d');
answerD.innerHTML = answersQuiz();

function answersQuiz() {
    const answers = [ 'Java', 'C', 'Python', 'JS' ];
    for (const id of [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]) {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        for (let i = 1; i < answers.length; i++) {
            var answerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        }
        element.innerText = answers[answerIndex];
        answers.splice(answerIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

The main thing I would like to know is this undefined problem. Any suggestions

Comment: kindly try to provide a minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const answerA = document.getElementById('a');
answerA.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerB = document.getElementById('b');
answerB.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerC = document.getElementById('c');
answerC.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
const answerD = document.getElementById('d');
answerD.innerHTML = answersQuiz();
```

answersQuiz() function is not returning any variable (undefined), so innerHTML writes undefined. In your code, in the function answersQuiz() innerText does actual job.

In result, you are calling the answersQuiz() function four times reduntantly. You should call it once and you should not write its return variable. (there is not any)

Replace above portion of the code with following;

```
answersQuiz();
```